# SPRING - Can't retrieve a ResponseEntity with Feign while sent correctly formated

Tags: java, spring, client, httpresponse, feign

I'm trying to communicate information between two micro services in Spring. One is sending a ResponseEntity with an Object in the body, but on the other side I can't seem to get the correct response. All the fields are null.

[this is the controller of my first microservice](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f2EqA.png)

[this is what is returned when called directly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/36Irr.png)

[this is the code inspection of the response before it's sent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cBgeO.png)

Then I try to recuperate this response in another micro service.

[This is the client](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SA3kY.png)

[This is the call to the first API](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vAjQK.png)

[This is the response I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jkVyN.png)

So I'm stuck there, not getting why my client can't access the data. I have set breakpoints in both of the application and the first one is correctly called.

You can find my code there : https://github.com/Shikatamo/B3Examples

I have tried for 3-4h, and I'm really stuck there. It looks like something really stupid from my part but I can't seem to put my finger on it. All help is greatly appreciated at this point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to get rid of ResponseEntity in your client:

```
@Component
@FeignClient("CourseStudent")
public interface ICourseStudentClient {

    @RequestLine("GET /{id}")
    CourseStudents getOneById(@Param("id") Long id);
}
```

Comment: how would this help get the status part of the response?